# Apply styles to a single element with firebug?

Tags: firebug

With firebug, how can I apply styles to a single element?

With Chrome inspector there is an empty inline selector ready for you to use (see below). I switched from firefox to chrome for web development for this reason, but now due to required addons I need to use firebug again.

```
element.style {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://second-cup-of-coffee.com/tweaking-the-inline-style-of-an-element-in-firebug/

```
I don’t know why I never tried this, but I finally figured out that simply right-clicking in Firebug’s style window gives you the option to “Edit Element Style…” Yes, it is that simple. Choosing that option will put an element.style option right at the top, just like in Chrome’s Web Inspector.
```